# Why can't I erase string's numeric characters?

Tags: c++, string, erase

I want to erase all numbers in a string (eventually all symbols and white spaces) and keep all letter characters in the string. What I am trying to ultimately do is search for palindromes from large blocks of text.

With what I got right now it will erase the numbers; plus all other non numeric characters after the first numeric character that gets erased. I want to know why this is doing this and what I can do to make it erase only the numeric characters.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <iterator>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
bool con = true;
while (con == true)
{
cout << "Enter a string: ";
string input;
getline(cin, input);

/** here is where I am attempting to erase all numeric characters in input string**/    
for(int i=0; i<input.length(); i++){

    if(isdigit(input.at(i))){

        string::iterator it;
        it=input.begin()+i;
        input.erase(i);
    break;
    }
}

string go;

cout << input << endl;

    cout << "Continue? y/n " << endl;
    getline(cin, go);
    if( go != "y")
        con = false;


}
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that you can use `std::remove_if` in conjunction with either a lambda or `std::not1` and `std::isalpha` to remove all but alphabetical characters. For just numeric characters, `std::remove_if` and `std::isdigit`.

Comment: Thanks. I'll have to use isalpha then.

Comment: @chris, `std::isalpha` will not work in this case, because it returns an `int`, not a `bool`. Because of the implicit type conversions necessary, it will fail in this case.

Comment: @NathanErnst, AFAIK, casting it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(int i=0; i<input.length(); i++){

    if(isdigit(input.at(i))){

        string::iterator it;
        it=input.begin()+i;
        input.erase(i);
    break;
    }
}
```

I don`t like that code snippet: **decide that to use iterators or indexes, I think you shoudn`t mix them**.
There is **error in you code:**  when you erase from a string it`s length also changes(so for loop will not work, instead **use while loop**)

```
string::iterator it = input.begin();

    while (it != input.end())
    {
         while( it != input.end() && isdigit(*it))
         {
              it = input.erase(it);
         }
         if (it != input.end())
             ++it;
    }
```

Comment: were is i from it = input.erase(i); ? using 'it' does not give the correct output.

Comment: opps, sorry I overlooked it, it should be ofcourse iterator. Thank you I shall make adjustments

Comment: w8ht gives the output of 8t. Its discarding every other character.

Comment: @Road Rash Where was";" after if, I corrected it, check it, all works fine - I checked

Comment: its doing alot better but I noticed the input 345hf3 returned 4hf. hello92 return hello2. Basically if there is two or more numbers together, it will return one number in it. I used !isalpha and I still gets the same results.

Comment: Awesome, I was trying the same thing with the amperstamp. It was a while loop that it needed to go into. Makes sense. I've learned a lot as always. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
cin >> inputString;
for(string::iterator begin = inputString.begin(), end = inputString.end(); begin != end;){
  if(isdigit(*begin)){
    begin = inputString.erase(begin);
  }else
    ++begin;
}
//cout << inputString;
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to research how `string.erase()` works; the version which takes one argument deletes everything after and including the index provided. What should fix your problem is changing `input.erase(i)` to `input.erase(i, 1)`.  The version which takes two arguments deletes an amount of characters equal to the second argument starting at the first arguments position.

Also, I don't see the purpose of these two lines in your program:

```
string::iterator it;
it=input.begin()+i;
```